# In google sheets is there any way to use importrange but maintain formatting? (no paid add-on)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In google sheets is there any way to use importrange but maintain formatting? Aware of SheetsGo but don't want a paid solution. Not referring to conditional formatting specifically, more row colors, etc.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research effforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 7):

You can't import formatting directly. But there is a simple solution, which I use all the time. For the sake of explanation, let's say your source spreadsheet is called "Source" and your destination spreadsheet is called "Destination." From there:

1.) Open Source and go to the sheet you want to have imported into Destination.

2.) Right-click on the tab that shows the sheet name. **Choose Copy to > Existing spreadsheet**. Use the search tool to find Destination. Click on that sheet.

3.) Open the Destination spreadsheet.The Source sheet will appear there, with the name "Copy of [sheet name]" and *with all formatting from Source*. Change the sheet name as you like. Then just click the upper-leftmost empty rectangle (between A and 1) to select the entire sheet and hit the Delete key. This will leave just your formatting. From here, you can now enter your IMPORTRANGE formula(s), and they'll populate without changing the formatting.

This might sound like a lot. But in actuality, it only takes 20 seconds to do.